# How to track revolution of DC motor?

Tags: arduino-uno, sensors, motor

I am currently trying to build a line follower robot that is designed to solve maze. This maze has a loop, thus it needs to know distance it already travelling (or at least I assume so, please let me know otherwise).

I am aware of a rotary encoder motor from Polulu ([for example](https://www.pololu.com/product/2821)) but it's not available in my country and shipping price is too expensive.

So I need to find way around it. Should I use Stepper motor? Is there any other way? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @yabbadabba - comments under questions are for seeking clarification about the question. Not for stating that your answer is the best one. People will vote for answers that they think are good, including yours, if they merit such votes. Your comments have been deleted.

Answer (score 5):

You can Use wheel encoders. You can even make your own wheel encoders with general parts like photoTransistor and lasor or led light. you can make your encoder or print it out in paper. The use little math to calculate the distance. It will give you measurement with good level of precision.

Basic principle:
[image]

[image]

more information at

[wheel Encoder](http://www.societyofrobots.com/sensors_encoder.shtml)

[another encoder](http://letsmakerobots.com/node/12293)

Comment: If the OP make their own hand built encoder then how do they know how accurate it is?

Comment: @yabbadabba, if the OP makes his own hand built encoder, he will know the number of openings in the wheel. He will be able to count the number of openings and measure the distance that the wheel travels, or simply perform the math of circumference equals pi times the diameter.

Comment: @fred_dot_u I think what your saying is likely to be  true if he makes it with a CNC machine

Comment: There's a fellow on YouTube (HomoFaciens) who makes amazing constructions with ordinary tools. His encoder wheel is cut out of sheet metal or cardboard depending on the device he's building. The slots are cut with scissors or metal shears and are mildly irregular, yet provide fractional control of the device. The founding principles of the physics of the encoder wheel care not about the sophistication of the construction. One can turn a bicycle wheel into an encoder, which happens to be how bicycle speedometers work! So many answers, so few characters.

Comment: @fred_dot_u    " (HomoFaciens) who makes amazing constructions with ordinary tools"- sounds like he's got a rare talent

Comment: One of his talents is his skill at presenting material for the benefit of so many, to make this sort of thing (encoding, in this case) easier to understand and to implement in one's own projects. As an example specific to this project, the OP could use or add toy wheels with spokes and install an optical sensor to trigger on the spokes. That would qualify as a hand-built encoder and the OP could count the spokes. The diameter and circumference can be measured as well. The OP's satisfaction can be gained by implementing something from materials on-hand (purchased) rather than CNC created.

Comment: @fred_dot_u " (HomoFaciens) who makes amazing constructions with ordinary tools"-there's a video of him building a rotary encoder- doesnt seem to use a toy wheel though. There's different ways to make , hand made, the encoder-by using print out on paper as it says in this answer

Comment: Guys guys. No need to use any tools. Print the graphichs on a photocopy paper and attached it on the wheel. Like in second link. Thanks but its 3 am n i feel so sleepy.

Answer (score 1):

You could add a rotary encoder to a motor yourself. Thought this is not as convenient as buying an all in one solution.

You can even build your own by making a disk with holes at regular intervals, and using an IR led, phototransistor pair on either side of the disk. You can even get all in one photo-interruptors. You could get them from an old computer-mouse. You might even be able to use the wheel/disk in it.

Another option is to add a magnet to the wheel, and a hall-effect sensor to the body. That way you can count the number of revolutions. (Though you probably want higher resolution than once per revolution).

Comment: how do you determine the accuracy of the hand built rotary encoder?

Comment: @yabbadabba - the ultimate accuracy mostly comes from accurately knowing the distance traveled per revolution of the wheel, for example you can measure over long distances, but you have to worry about slipping and straightness of path.  There can also be issues with regularity of spacing and eccentricity of the pattern relative to the shaft (or the wheel itself relative to the axle) but while those are serious concerns in say, a CNC machine tool, with moderate care they will probably not be problematic in a maze robot.

Comment: @ChrisStratton "probably not be problematic in a maze robot". Its not clear to me too-if it would definitely be a problem

Answer (score 1):

An optical encoder would be the best solution in my opinion. The next best thing would be to use a stepper motor. You can find plenty of stepper motors in old printers - which is good if the budget is tight.

The problem with a stepper motor is that you have no feedback on where the motor actually is. You drive it forward say 100 pulses, but without any feedback you have no idea if there was any slip or overrun. This is called [open loop](https://www.servocity.com/open-loop-vs-closed-loop) control.

However, both of these methods are measuring/driving the rotation of the motor. What happens if the wheel doesn't have enough grip and slips and does a sort of burnout. For this reason, I have seen some maze robots use an old mouse to measure the distance the robot has actually travelled. This was not necessarily very accurate over long distances but was a cheap way of measuring distance travelled.

Comment: If they go down the route of interfacing to USB mouse directly to ATMEGA then they need a USB host solution-  this has already been done (mainly in software)-see https://courses.cit.cornell.edu/ee476/FinalProjects/s2007/blh36_cdl28_dct23/blh36_cdl28_dct23/

Comment: An old PS2 mouse is easier to interface to Arduino.  There is documentation and library at http://playground.arduino.cc/ComponentLib/Ps2mouse

Comment: Obviously that depends on if OP has ps2 mouse , USB mouse is more common. For the USB  related  link I gave the hardware part I would say are easier to get.

Comment: @sa_leinad, your suggestion is sound. The type of mouse is not as important if one is willing to dissect to a board level. I've dissected a mouse to use the spoked wheel inside which has a properly aligned optical trigger pair, along with the plastic structure to keep things in place. Counting pulses and direction over a known course, with the appropriate math would serve as a useful distance measuring device. Discarded printers also contain linear and rotary encoders with opto-pairs, but harder to use in a robot!

Comment: @fred_dot_u has brought up a good point - if you can get your hands on some of the really old mice that have the ball inside (instead of the red optical sensor) there are two quadrature encoders (slotted wheel and optical sensor, one from the x direction and the other from the y direction) that can be harvested from the mouse.

Comment: In modern mice, there is a quadrature encoder in the scroll wheel. Here are some links on how to harvest the encoders: http://www.seattlerobotics.org/encoder/200311/johnson/Mousebot.html http://www.boondog.com/tutorials/mouse/mouseHackBeforeWeb.htm

Comment: @sa_leinad, the funny thing about your reply to my comment was that I was referring to the mouse wheel and was ambiguous in my description. I have three mouse wheels harvested with the circuit board and mouse housing. By keeping the parts together, it allows easy access for wiring and mechanical placement too. The unwanted portions can be cut free, reducing the size of the bundle to be installed, while the solder pads on the circuit boards facilitate the wiring. Your link is very supportive of the OP's purpose.